# How to click overlapping element in CSS?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, slider, overlap

I'm making a custom slider in react, but there's a problem when the thumbs overlap.
When the two sliders-thumbs overlap, I want to move what I touched but I can't focus it
because the right thumb has a high priority.

So I found a similar reference. In this code, even if the thumbs overlap I can click the left thumb, how is it possible?

https://codepen.io/MarioD/pen/WwXbgr

[image]

```js
$(function() {

  // Initiate Slider
  $('#slider-range').slider({
    range: true,
    min: 10000,
    max: 110000,
    step: 100,
    values: [45000, 75000]
  });

  // Move the range wrapper into the generated divs
  $('.ui-slider-range').append($('.range-wrapper'));

  // Apply initial values to the range container
  $('.range').html('<span class="range-value"><sup>$</sup>' + $('#slider-range').slider("values", 0).toString().replace(/(\d)(?=(\d\d\d)+(?!\d))/g, "$1,") + '</span><span class="range-divider"></span><span class="range-value"><sup>$</sup>' + $("#slider-range").slider("values", 1).toString().replace(/(\d)(?=(\d\d\d)+(?!\d))/g, "$1,") + '</span>');

  // Show the gears on press of the handles
  $('.ui-slider-handle, .ui-slider-range').on('mousedown', function() {
    $('.gear-large').addClass('active');
  });

  // Hide the gears when the mouse is released
  // Done on document just incase the user hovers off of the handle
  $(document).on('mouseup', function() {
    if ($('.gear-large').hasClass('active')) {
      $('.gear-large').removeClass('active');
    }
  });

  // Rotate the gears
  var gearOneAngle = 0,
    gearTwoAngle = 0,
    rangeWidth = $('.ui-slider-range').css('width');

  $('.gear-one').css('transform', 'rotate(' + gearOneAngle + 'deg)');
  $('.gear-two').css('transform', 'rotate(' + gearTwoAngle + 'deg)');

  $('#slider-range').slider({
    slide: function(event, ui) {

      // Update the range container values upon sliding

      $('.range').html('<span class="range-value"><sup>$</sup>' + ui.values[0].toString().replace(/(\d)(?=(\d\d\d)+(?!\d))/g, "$1,") + '</span><span class="range-divider"></span><span class="range-value"><sup>$</sup>' + ui.values[1].toString().replace(/(\d)(?=(\d\d\d)+(?!\d))/g, "$1,") + '</span>');

      // Get old value
      var previousVal = parseInt($(this).data('value'));

      // Save new value
      $(this).data({
        'value': parseInt(ui.value)
      });

      // Figure out which handle is being used
      if (ui.values[0] == ui.value) {

        // Left handle
        if (previousVal > parseInt(ui.value)) {
          // value decreased
          gearOneAngle -= 7;
          $('.gear-one').css('transform', 'rotate(' + gearOneAngle + 'deg)');
        } else {
          // value increased
          gearOneAngle += 7;
          $('.gear-one').css('transform', 'rotate(' + gearOneAngle + 'deg)');
        }

      } else {

        // Right handle
        if (previousVal > parseInt(ui.value)) {
          // value decreased
          gearOneAngle -= 7;
          $('.gear-two').css('transform', 'rotate(' + gearOneAngle + 'deg)');
        } else {
          // value increased
          gearOneAngle += 7;
          $('.gear-two').css('transform', 'rotate(' + gearOneAngle + 'deg)');
        }

      }

      if (ui.values[1] === 110000) {
        if (!$('.range-alert').hasClass('active')) {
          $('.range-alert').addClass('active');
        }
      } else {
        if ($('.range-alert').hasClass('active')) {
          $('.range-alert').removeClass('active');
        }
      }
    }
  });

  // Prevent the range container from moving the slider
  $('.range, .range-alert').on('mousedown', function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
  });

});
```

```css
// Apply a natural box layout model to all elements
html{
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*, *:before, *:after{
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

html,
body{
  height: 100%;
  min-width: 500px;
}

body{
  background: #e8e8e8;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}

sup{
  font-size: 80%;
  vertical-align: top;
  position: relative;
  top: 1px;
}

.wrapper{
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.container{
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
}


// Slider

.slider-wrapper{
  width: 500px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  font-family: arial;
}

.ui-slider{
  background: #efefef;
  border: 1px solid #d2d2d2;
  height: 20px;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 100px;
}

.ui-slider-range{
  background: #71c0ff;
  height: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  border-top: 1px solid #5d99c8;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #5d99c8;
  transform: translateY(-1px);

  &:after{
    content: '';
    width: 100%;
    height: 1px;
    background: #fff;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    opacity: 0.3;
  }
}

.ui-slider-handle{
  background: #555;
  position: absolute;
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  top: 50%;
  display: block;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  border-radius: 100px;
  z-index: 10;
  background: linear-gradient(#555, #454545);
  cursor: move; /* fallback if grab cursor is unsupported */
  cursor: grab;
  cursor: -moz-grab;
  cursor: -webkit-grab;
  box-shadow: inset -2px -2px 6px 2px rgba(0,0,0, 0.1);
  transition: width 0.1s;

  &:focus{
    outline: none;
  }

  &:active{
    cursor: grabbing;
    cursor: -moz-grabbing;
    cursor: -webkit-grabbing;
  }
}

.ui-state-active{
  width: 22px;
}



// Range Indicator

.range-wrapper{
  position: absolute;
  top: -50px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}

.range{
  background: #fff;
  white-space: nowrap;
  border: 1px solid #d2d2d2;
  border-radius: 2px;
  font-size: 13px;
  letter-spacing: 0.02em;
  color: #555;
  width: 150px;
  z-index: 10;
  position: relative;

  &:after{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    border-left: 67px solid transparent;
    border-right: 67px solid transparent;
    border-top: 6px solid #d2d2d2;
  }
}

.range-value{
  width: 74px;
  padding: 8px 0;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: background 0.1s;
}

.range-divider{
  width: 1px;
  display: inline-block;

  &:after{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 50%;
    width: 1px;
    height: 100%;
    background: #d2d2d2;
    content: '';
  }
}

.range-alert{
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 0;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  background: #fff;
  border-top-right-radius: 2px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 2px;
  border: 1px solid #d2d2d2;
  color: #0E0E0E;
  line-height: 15px;
  transition: right 0.2s;

  &.active{
    right: -15px;
  }
}



// Price Markers

.marker{
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  padding-top: 16px;
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #555;
  letter-spacing: 0.05em;
  transform: translateX(-50%);

  &:after{
    content: '';
    width: 1px;
    height: 8px;
    background: #d2d2d2;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
  }
}

.marker-0{
  &:after{
    display: none;
  }
}

.marker-25{
  left: 25%;
}

.marker-50{
  left: 50%;
}

.marker-75{
  left: 75%;
}

.marker-100{
  right: 0;
  transform: translateX(50%);

  &:after{
    display: none;
  }
}



// Gears

.gear-wrapper{
  position: absolute;
  top: -14px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  z-index: 5;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  width: 150px;
  height: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.gear-large{
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background: #d2d2d2;
  border-radius: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 18px;
  left: 18px;
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  transition: top 0.15s;

  &:after{
    position: absolute;
    content: '';
    width: 28px;
    height: 28px;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    background: #e8e8e8;
    border-radius: 100px;
  }

  &:nth-child(2){
    background: #d2d2d2;
    left: auto;
    right: 18px;

    & .gear-tooth{
      background: #d2d2d2;
    }
  }

  &.active{
    top: 4px;
  }
}

.gear-tooth{
  width: 22%;
  height: 114%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform-origin: 0 0;
  background: #d2d2d2;
  border-radius: 2px;

  &:nth-child(2){
    transform: rotate(90deg) translate(-50%, -50%);
  }

  &:nth-child(3){
    transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-50%, -50%);
  }

  &:nth-child(4){
    transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-50%, -50%);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="container">

    <div class="slider-wrapper">
      <div id="slider-range"></div>

      <div class="range-wrapper">
        <div class="range"></div>
        <div class="range-alert">+</div>

        <div class="gear-wrapper">
          <div class="gear-large gear-one">
            <div class="gear-tooth"></div>
            <div class="gear-tooth"></div>
            <div class="gear-tooth"></div>
            <div class="gear-tooth"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="gear-large gear-two">
            <div class="gear-tooth"></div>
            <div class="gear-tooth"></div>
            <div class="gear-tooth"></div>
            <div class="gear-tooth"></div>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>

      <div class="marker marker-0"><sup>$</sup>10,000</div>
      <div class="marker marker-25"><sup>$</sup>35,000</div>
      <div class="marker marker-50"><sup>$</sup>60,000</div>
      <div class="marker marker-75"><sup>$</sup>85,000</div>
      <div class="marker marker-100"><sup>$</sup>110,000+</div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```